# Which squashfs file in Ubuntu 22.04 live server image should be used?

Tags: boot, 22.04, live-cd, squashfs

I found the `squashfs` file in Ubuntu 22.04 image pretty much different from previous releases.
There is no `filesystem.squashfs` file under the `casper` directory after mounting the ISO.
Instead, there will be 5 different `squashfs` files including:

- `casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.squashfs`
- `casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic-hwe.squashfs`
- `casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.squashfs`
- `casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs`
- `casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.squashfs`

There is a `filesystem.manifest` but no corresponding `filesystem.squashfs`.

What's the difference/relationship between them and which one or ones should be used to get the similar contents as `filesystem.squashfs` of previous releases?

Comment: You could try using `7z l` to list the contents of each of the `.squashfs` archives.

Comment: That one is the only one with bin, etc. But it is also so much smaller than previous filesystems...

Answer (score 3):

OK, `casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.squashfs`.This is the one.
Got into `chroot`, installed stuff inside, squashed the filesystem again and created the ISO. Works like a charm!!